# cannot change language of text based on localStorage at button click

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I made buttons to switch language of data on click based on localStorage `language` item value, but it does not work as expected

HTML:

```
<a id="arbutton" href="#ar">arabic</a>
<a id="enbutton" href="#en">english</a>
<a id="" href="localStorage1.html">page</a>
<!--     data here will change -->
<div id="hello">yes language</div>
```

JS:

```
var creatbtnAr = document.querySelector('#arbutton');
var creatbtnEn = document.querySelector('#enbutton');

// button language arabic
creatbtnAr.addEventListener('click', event => {
   localStorage.setItem("language", "ar");
   console.log(localStorage.language);
});
// button language english
creatbtnEn.addEventListener('click', event => {
   localStorage.setItem("language", "en");
   console.log(localStorage.language);
});

// methods 
var lg = localStorage.getItem.language;
function translate(lg) {
   if(lg == 'ar') {
      document.querySelector('#hello').textContent = 'u arabic';
   }
   if(lg == 'en') {
      document.querySelector('#hello').textContent = 'u english';
   }
}
```

https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var creatbtnAr = document.querySelector('#arbutton');
var creatbtnEn = document.querySelector('#enbutton');

// button language arabic
creatbtnAr.addEventListener('click', event => {
    localStorage.setItem("language", "ar");
    console.log(localStorage.language);
    translate();

});
// button language english
creatbtnEn.addEventListener('click', event => {
   localStorage.setItem("language", "en");
    console.log(localStorage.language);
    translate();
});

// methods 
function translate() {
    const lg = localStorage.getItem("language");
    if(lg == 'ar') {
        document.querySelector('#hello').textContent = 'u arabic';
    }
    if(lg == 'en') {
        document.querySelector('#hello').textContent = 'u english';
    }
}
```

Comment: this will read `language` item from localStorage everytime you execute `translate()` function (when either en or ar button is pressed)

Comment: sorry, my English so bad :(